# logstash - add only first time value

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch-2.0

Here's what I want, it's a bit the opposite of incremental data.

some data's are logs with a specific token, and I want to be able to keep (or to show in Elasticsearch) only the first submitted data, the oldiest information of each token.

I want to ignore any new log of the same token ?

How can I do that ? is it in logstash or elasticsearch ?

Thanks

**Updates 2016-05-31**

I think we can see that in different perspective. but globally what I want is the table like in the picture, but without the red lines, I want them to be ignored by logstash, or not display in ES queries.
[image]

I know it can be done, if I was able to add any flag in those lines I want to delete, but it's not possible, the only fact that tell us they can be removed is because we already have a key first-AAA that has been logged before. 
At the logging process, we don't have this information.

Comment: Can you show some sample log lines and what you'd like to see in ES?

Comment: Check the update on the main description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [`elasticsearch` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html). The filter would check in ES if the record already exists and if it is the case, we ask Logstash to just drop the line.

Note that I'm making the assumption that the `Id` field (`AAA`) is used as the document `_id` and is also present in the document as the `Id` field. Feel free to change whatever needs to, but this will work.

```
input {
   ...
}
filter {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      query => "_type:your_type AND _id:%{[Id]}"
      fields => {"Id" => "found"}
   }
   if [found] {
      drop {}
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I'll do some test, and get you the bounty. And Yes AAA was my document_id

Comment: Awesome, happy testing!

Comment: I cannot make it work.
I tried several variation, I always getting a problem with the elasticsearch serving that fall down I think, would you agree to help me on private ?

Comment: Sure, we can try. [Join the chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113470/logstash-add-only-first-time-value)

Comment: You've got new messages ;)

Comment: You've got new message :D

Comment: You've got new message :)

Comment: Hi :), you've got new message